# How can I display info from a sensormanager class in an android project?

Tags: android, android-activity, sensors

I have a sensormanager for my temperature sensor, and I used the templat from the android repository:

```
 public class SensorActivity extends Activity, implements SensorEventListener {
     private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
     private final Sensor mAccelerometer;

     public SensorActivity() {
         mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
         mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
     }

     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
     }

     protected void onPause() {
         super.onPause();
         mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
     }

     public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
     }

     public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
     }
 }
```

But with temperature instead of accelerometer.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get the actual numbers from here to my main activity in a form I can display, preferrably in a way that constantly updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values measured by the sensor are received through the onSensorChanged method. Thats why you had to implement the SensorEventListener and register your class as the listener. This will get called whenever the value read by the sensor changes so you can just do whatever you need to do to display the data in there and it will keep updating as long as the class is registered as a listener.

In your case you probably want to make your MainActivity (if thats where the data is being displayed) implement the SensorEventListener interface and follow a similar pattern to the one used in the example you posted.

The values measured (as well as some other important information) is passed to you using the SensorEvent parameter. For some more detailed information on how to extract the data from the given object take a look at the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) for the class.

As mentioned in the documentation linked above, the measured temperature is stored in the first slot of the values array so you can extract it like this

```
public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event) {
    final float temperature = event.values[0];
    // Now that you have the temperature value, you can do 
    // whatever you want with it 
    this.doSomethingWithTemperatureValue(temperature);
}
```